# Replace spaces in string with a specific character in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string:

```
1 Vectorial position [X Y] X 682.9 1.0 -1.0 X 682.6 X -0.3 ----.-----
```

In this string there are spaces which are to be replaced by any special character for splitting the string.

Required output is:

```
1 ~ Vectorial position [X Y] ~ X ~ 682.9 ~ 1.0 ~ -1.0 ~ X ~ 682.6 ~ X ~-0.3 ~ ----.-----****
```

For the above I had tried using:

```
$yval_arr[$i] =~s/ /~/g;
$yval_arr[$i] =~ s/(.)\1\1+/$1$1$1/g;
$yval_arr[$i] =~s/(.)\1{1,}/$1$1$1/g;
```

but using this the first character repeats it self 2 times i.e. if it is `11` in the beginning it becomes `111`.

Please help.

Comment: Please reformat your question, showing input, your code, and expected output (using code blocks)

Comment: Add 4 spaces in front of code to have it formatted correctly.  Do you intend that the spaces ` ` are replaced by space-tilda-space ` ~ `?

Comment: Why is `****` in required output? Why you need that in output?

Comment: yes it is replaced by '~' . but the spaces size vary in the string , in 1 and vectorial position there is a single' ' space but in some place the there are 3 sapce.'   '.

Comment: @ serenesat  - **** it is required it is a part of the string .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would split your data into a description and data, and then operate on the data.  This makes it easier to understand and debug.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $str = '1 Vectorial position [X Y] X 682.9 1.0 -1.0 X 682.6 X -0.3 ----.-----';
my ($description, $data) = $str =~ m|^(.*\])(.*)$|; # $1 - everything upto [X Y]
                                                    # $2 - everything else

$data =~ s|\s+| ~ |g; # Replace one or more spaces with space-tilda-space everywhere
$description =~ s|^(\d+)(\s+)|$1 ~ |; # Likewise in description, between number and label

my $result = join '', $description, $data;
print "BEFORE '$str'\n";
print "AFTER  '$result'\n";
```

Outputs:

```
BEFORE '1 Vectorial position [X Y] X 682.9 1.0 -1.0 X 682.6 X -0.3 ----.-----'
AFTER  '1 ~ Vectorial position [X Y] ~ X ~ 682.9 ~ 1.0 ~ -1.0 ~ X ~ 682.6 ~ X ~ -0.3 ~ ----.-----'
```

If we update `$str` to:

```
my $str = '1 Vectorial position [Z] Z 267.0 1.0 -1.0 Z 267.3 Z 0.3 -----.-*---';
```

The output is:

```
BEFORE '1 Vectorial position [Z] Z 267.0 1.0 -1.0 Z 267.3 Z 0.3 -----.-*---'
AFTER  '1 ~ Vectorial position [Z] ~ Z ~ 267.0 ~ 1.0 ~ -1.0 ~ Z ~ 267.3 ~ Z ~ 0.3 ~ -----.-*---'
```

Comment: I guess OP wants `~` after first 1 also like: `1 ~ Vectorial position [X Y] ~ X .....`, So adding this `$description =~ s|\s+| ~ |;` will give the above output.

Comment: 1 Vectorial position [Z] Z 267.0 1.0 -1.0 Z 267.3 Z 0.3 -----.-*--- not working for this string

Answer (score 0):

```
my $str = "1 Vectorial position [X Y] X 682.9 1.0 -1.0 X 682.6 X -0.3 ----.-----";
# first insert ~ before all X with leading space char
$str =~ s/( X)/ ~$1/g;
# replace all numbers with numbers + ~
$str =~ s/([- ]\d+\.\d+)/ ~ $1/g;
# replace the first space with " ~ "
$str =~ s/ / ~ /;
```

Comment: Did you check the output of your program. It doesn't provide OP's desire output. It will replace every whitespace with `~`. And yes escape is not required for `~`.

Comment: That is exactly what I understood as his requirement!

Comment: Did you not see required output?

Comment: I see the point, did not understand his requirement very well. Changed my solution now.

Answer (score 0):

I would split the original string on spaces, and then do some creative field extraction: I assume the first word and the last 9 words in the string are separate fields, and what's left over is to become the 2nd field in the output.

```
$str = "1 Vectorial position [X Y] X 682.9 1.0 -1.0 X 682.6 X -0.3 ----.-----";
@words = split ' ', $str;
@fields = splice @words, -9;
$first = shift @words;
unshift @fields, $first, join(" ", @words);
say join(" ~ ", @fields);
```

```
1 ~ Vectorial position [X Y] ~ X ~ 682.9 ~ 1.0 ~ -1.0 ~ X ~ 682.6 ~ X ~ -0.3 ~ ----.-----
```